# how can I retain text-selected status when screen rotation in android

Tags: android, browser, webview, find

How can I retain text-selected find status when screen rotation in android

In my Application, I use Webview to show the website, then I long press the website content, to create the system default Actionmode,the "select"　,"copy"　,"share"　,"find" menu show, then I click the "find" item　the selected word can be saw in find text editor. **But when I rotate the screen, all the menu and find text editor is destroyed**, return to the initial status when I open the website at beginning.
My question is after screen rotation ,**what can I do to retain the find status?**

PS: I know when the screen rotating, the Activity is destroyed and recreated, so the status before rotating lost. But **I do not know what object should I save in onSaveIntanceState() method**.
    Also I do not want to use the android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml file.

I did like below

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    webView.saveState(outState);
}
```

Then recover this in your onCreate after the webview has been re-inflated of course:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.blah);
   if (savedInstanceState != null)
      ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

but it does not work, the text-selected-find status is still lost.

I think if I can get the system default ActionMode instance,so I can save it, 
but I don't find any way to get that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10126961/1952459) solution. I think you will get a good idea on how to use `onSaveInstanceState()` method.

EDIT:
Put it as below

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

You need to put these two methods in your class and override them. Also, you did not put `super` constructor, which is important.

Comment: But in onSaveInstanceState(),**what Object should I save**,can you explain something more

Comment: You can save the Bundle object from `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Comment: Check the EDIT part of my answer and also try to implement the `Parcelable` class as shown at the link I shared.