# Keepin the music Playing Through Rotation

Tags: android

What is the best way to save the instance of my MediaPlayer playing through rotation of the device. I know about the setRetainState() method but I am not using a fragment.  What would be the best way to attach the state of my MediaPlayer to the bundle so the music continues to play after the user rotates the device.

Comment: Try this solution ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126845/handle-screen-rotation-without-losing-data-android/20279603#20279603

Comment: use service. they keep on working in background and doesnt get affected by screen rotation or run in the background even if the user switches to another application.

Answer (score -1):

Use onConfigurationChanged method of activity to detect Orientation Change

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

```
// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Edit the appropriate element in your AndroidManifest.XML like this to include the android:configChanges