# Android app crashed when change orientation

Tags: java, android, xml

When the orientation of app change this error is occur kindly help me

```
W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.explore_kpk, PID: 24892
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.explore_kpk/com.example.explore_kpk.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1803)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     ***Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference***
        ***at com.example.explore_kpk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:121)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)***
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1803) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24892 SIG: 9
```

This is code in which error pointing**
at `com.example.explore_kpk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:121)`

```
  RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyler_view);

        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, recyclerList);
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(recyclerList, new Random(seed));

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this, mNoOfColumns);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is saying that you are trying to use `setLayoutManager` on `null object reference`. This means that your `recylcerView` is null at the moment. I don't see your whole code so I can't give you an instant solution. What I can say for you is that each time the screen orientation is changed your current activity will be destroyed and called again. So, `onCreate` will be called again and everything else like you just started new `Activity`. Sometimes issues happen here so there is few options on how to handle these events.

---

**Retaining an object during a configuration change**

What this means is for you to keep your data while screen rotation is happening. This can be done with Bundle but if you have a large set of data then it is better to use the ViewModel object. How to do this check here:

- [Retaining an object during a configuration change | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)
- [ViewModel Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)
- [Helpful answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45294332/14759470)

---

**Handling the configuration change yourself**

This other option comes with big **CAUTION**. Consider this as a last resort when you really need to avoid restarts because of a configuration change. What this does is preventing your activity from the restart. If you can't save your instance then I would recommend doing this but first, try to play with ViewModel and Bundles to fix this issue.

- [Handling the configuration change yourself | Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

How to do this?

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
```

add `android:configChanges` line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside your `<activity/>` tag.